# Python Selenium: Scraping From Lowes, Prices seem to be location locked?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a script that is cllecting data from Lowes and it appears to be working. I t scrapes the sku and description with no problem but it does not seem to be locating the price as the array I created is empty when I run a check. I believe this to be because of some kind of location lock. When I look at the web page in my browser I can see the price just fine but when I look at the webpage when Selenium is running the price is not viewable and is replaced with "Select store for availability' Does anyone know how to work around this? Here is the url I am working with: https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-panels-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858283

And here is my program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

def scrape_page_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
    container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')

    # scroll down to load all content on the page
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)

    skus = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltip-custom')
    prices = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.prdt-actl-pr')
    description = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.titl-cnt.titl.brnd-desc')

    return skus, prices, description

def pagination(url, pages=1):
    prod_num = []
    prod_price = []
    prod_desc = []

    page_num = 0
    # iterate over the pages
    for i in range(1, pages + 1):
        # print(f"this is page {i}")
        driver.get(f"{url}?Nao={page_num}")

        skus, prices, description = scrape_page_data()

        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)
        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)
        for desc in description:
            prod_desc.append(desc.text)
        print(f"prod_num: {prod_num}")
        print(f"prod_price: {prod_price}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {prod_desc}")
        print(f"prod_num: {len(prod_num)}")
        print(f"prod_price: {len(prod_price)}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {len(prod_desc)}")

        # increment it by 24 since each page has 24 data
        page_num += 24
        time.sleep(1)

    return prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc


# set the website URL and initialize the Chrome driver
website = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-panels-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858283'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--geolocation=47.8410,-122.2947") # set geolocation to Lynnwood, WA
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# call the pagination function to scrape data and store it in three separate lists
prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc = pagination(website, pages=1)

# convert the three lists to a pandas dataframe and save it as a CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price, 'brand': prod_desc})
df.to_csv('lowes.csv', index=False)
print(df)

# quit the Chrome driver
driver.quit()
```

I have never ran into this issue before. I did a very similar scrape on home depot and did not run into this problem. If anyone could help show me a solution integrated into my program that would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a few days lol

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just select a store from the dropdown? Also, you've asked a LOT of questions and have yet to upvote or select any answers on ANY of them. The way you reward people on the site for spending their time helping you is to upvote helpful answers, choose an answer and accept it.

Comment: @JeffC i do not have enough reputation to upvote people yet or else I would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely As a Workaround just use Undetected Chromdriver [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)
It will bypass any anti bot mechanisms used by the website due to which might be the reason it was not auto selecting the location

Tried your code with same and Store is auto selected now
[image]

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time


def scrape_page_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
    container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')

    # scroll down to load all content on the page
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)

    skus = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltip-custom')
    prices = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.prdt-actl-pr')
    description = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.titl-cnt.titl.brnd-desc')

    return skus, prices, description


def pagination(url, pages=1):
    prod_num = []
    prod_price = []
    prod_desc = []

    page_num = 0
    # iterate over the pages
    for i in range(1, pages + 1):
        # print(f"this is page {i}")
        driver.get(f"{url}?Nao={page_num}")

        skus, prices, description = scrape_page_data()

        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)
        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)
        for desc in description:
            prod_desc.append(desc.text)
        print(f"prod_num: {prod_num}")
        print(f"prod_price: {prod_price}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {prod_desc}")
        print(f"prod_num: {len(prod_num)}")
        print(f"prod_price: {len(prod_price)}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {len(prod_desc)}")

        # increment it by 24 since each page has 24 data
        page_num += 24
        time.sleep(1)

    return prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc


# set the website URL and initialize the Chrome driver
website = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-panels-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858283'
options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--geolocation=47.8410,-122.2947")  # set geolocation to Lynnwood, WA
driver = uc.Chrome()


# call the pagination function to scrape data and store it in three separate lists
prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc = pagination(website, pages=1)

# convert the three lists to a pandas dataframe and save it as a CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price, 'brand': prod_desc})
df.to_csv('lowes.csv', index=False)
print(df)

# quit the Chrome driver
driver.quit()
```